# Is it possible to enable or disable single sign-on for some application in thinktecture identity server v3?

Tags: single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server

I am using Thinktecture identity server v3 for single sign-on. If I logged-in in one application, then it never asks the credentials to login from second app onwards. It works great.

I need the option to enable or disable the single sign-on feature based on application. I need that application to ask credentials to login for every time. Is it possible?

Comment: This is exactly what single sign on mean. You only need to sign on once to use all your application. As long as you have the sign on cookie for identity  server you will not be asked for credentials. You can try customizing cookie expiration for identity server but you will loose the benefits of single sign on.

Comment: Though we are using single sign-on, some applications related to payments / transactions needs to avoid single sign-on.